# How to make console program to disappear and work in background?

Tags: console, background

How can I make console program disappear and work in the background?
I mean, I don't want to see the program, but I want to see it running in the task manager.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that you're trying to do this on Windows?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming Windows and .NET:

You could set its output type to "Windows Application", and it will not open the console window....

Or you could create a Windows Service...

Answer (score 2):

You could alternatively make one that goes to the system tray. This would also allow you to add a Kill Process directly from the system tray instead of going to the task manager. In .NET I have used the following:
http://www.developer.com/net/csharp/article.php/3336751

This may offer a few advantages.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a MS Windows XP environment:

My suggestion would be to consider making a [Windows Service](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/window_service11262005045007AM/window_service.aspx) to do what you are asking, though another possibility would be to set something up within msconfig to run the program at startup or in the startup group within the "Start->All Programs->StartUp" section.

If you are on a Mac, Linux or some other O/S, there may exist a similar function to act as a place to run programs within the background.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows try

```
start command.exe
```

If you are using *nix

```
nohup command
```

Comment: 'start' doesn't do that.  It "Starts a separate window to run a specified program or command."  (quoting directly from 'start /?')

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you cannot modify the console application and make it a windowless application you could create a windowless application that launches the console program and redirects all the standard input and output streams to "dummy" streams.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows use `ShowWindow(FindWindowA("ConsoleWindowClass", NULL), false)` to hide the console window. It will still be running in the background and is not visible on the taskbar.

However you will have to run a task manager like `Taskmgr.exe` to find it and shut it down.

```
#include <windows.h>  
#include <iostream>     
using namespace std;


int main () {   
    ShowWindow(FindWindowA("ConsoleWindowClass", NULL), false);
    while(true) {
                 // Do your hidden stuff here
    }   
return 0;
}
```